# How to use MySqli SELECT with OR condition correct in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im trying to display all the data that is the as my `query` but somehow, i don't know how to do that using mysqli prepared

here is my code:

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';
include 'header.php';

    $master = 'MASTER';
    $chck = 'CHCK';
    $second_engineer = '2E';
    $second_mate = '2M';
    $third_engineer = '3E';
    $third_mate = '3M';
    $ce = 'CE';
    $bsn = 'BSN';
    $ab = 'AB';
    $olr = 'OLR';
    $dcdt = 'DCDT';
    $egdt = 'EGDT';
    $cook = 'COOK';
    $messman = 'MESSMN';
    $crew_status = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? AND `crew_status` = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssssss', $crew_status, $master, $chck, $second_engineer, $second_mate, $third_engineer, $third_mate, $ce, $bsn, $ab, $olr, $dcdt, $egdt, $cook, $messman);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, $age, $month, $day, $year, $birth_place, $gender, $martial_status, $religion, $nationality, $email_address, $address_1, $address_2, $course, $school_graduated, $remarks, $note, $date_added, $crew_status, $crew_rank, $image_name, $updated_photo, $passport_registration, $passport_expiration);



?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>FULL NAME</td>
        <td>RANK</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".sprintf("%s%s%s", $first_name, $middle_name, $last_name)."</td>";
            echo "<td>".sprintf("%s", $crew_rank)."</td>";
            echo "<td>".sprintf("%s", $crew_status)."</td>";
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this code does not give me an output. only plain page

Comment: also used that but still no display

Comment: why the `AND` is typo?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see that it was a different column in the last test.

Comment: Can you show some sample data, the values of the variables, and the expected output?

Comment: the expected output must be `crew_status` is `PENDING FOR LINEUP` and also the `crew_rank` could be `MASTER` or `CHCK` or `2E` something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In programming, the KISS principal appllies. Your code can be simplified hugely

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE `crew_rank` IN ".
         "('MASTER','CHCK','2M','3E','3M','CE','BSN','AB','OLR','DCDT','EGDT','COOK','MESSMN')
        AND `crew_status` = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP'";
```

You don't even need a prepared statement here, because you are only using constants.

If you continue to get an empty page, did you consider that possibility that you may not have any matching rows in your database? Please copy paste the above into the mysql console and show the result.

Comment: used that query earlier and worked. im just wondering how to do it in prepared statement

Comment: The answer is you don't need a prepared statement. You use prepared statements only when you need to bind a variable. YOu have  made variables out of constants, just to be able to use a prepared statement. The simplest solution is always the best solution.